# How to import specific data from another spreadsheet in google sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to import specific data from another worksheet using the below formula. Reason being not to let other party to get hold of all the information, only the necessary data for them to work on.

Currently this formula not working. Any suggestions on how I can make it work?

`=FILTER(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1h2Qbxs-SuFpcPZzB3-2-VzBh3FTA9dH5_oOmtgTpBSs/edit#gid=0","Sheet1!$A:$D"),IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1h2Qbxs-SuFpcPZzB3-2-VzBh3FTA9dH5_oOmtgTpBSs/edit#gid=0","Sheet1!$B:$B=Nepal!$B$2"))`

Im trying to get data only related to Agent Ali.

[image: How I want it to show]

Link to the test spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1h2Qbxs-SuFpcPZzB3-2-VzBh3FTA9dH5_oOmtgTpBSs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Bear in mind that for the `IMPORTRANGE` to work you only need the `sheet ID`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mention:

> Im trying to get data only related to Agent Ali.

You can use this simple query formula:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("______","Sheet1!A1:D"),"where Col2='Ali'",1)
```

*(As always do modify ranges according to your needs)*